# Accessing instance field inf foreach removes instance

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have the following method:

```
private void ResolveRiver(IEnumerable<Barge> riverBarges)
{
    Barge currentBarge = riverBarges.FirstOrDefault();
    if (currentBarge == null) return;
    var groupedBarges = riverBarges.Where(b => currentBarge.MileMarker + 0.5d >= b.MileMarker && !b.IsGrouped);
    BargeGroup group = new BargeGroup { Barges = groupedBarges };
    m_bargeGroups.Add(group);
    foreach (Barge barge in group.Barges)
    {
        barge.IsGrouped = true;
    }
    IEnumerable<Barge> otherBarges = riverBarges.Except(groupedBarges);
    //ResolveRiver(otherBarges);
}
```

`riverBarges` is a ascending sortered `IEnumerable`. After foreach loop `group.Barges` is empty and I really wonder why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because `group.Barges` is an `IEnumerable<T>` (it's actually a `WhereEnumerableIterator`), which is executed each time you invoke it. The iterator will yield the values one at time, but it doesn't store the projected values. What you should do is materialize the query first, and then loop over the stored `List<T>` or `T[]`:

```
var groupedBarges = riverBarges.Where(b => currentBarge.MileMarker + 0.5d >= b.MileMarker
                                           && !b.IsGrouped)
                               .ToList();

BargeGroup group = new BargeGroup { Barges = groupedBarges };
m_bargeGroups.Add(group);
foreach (Barge barge in group.Barges)
{
    barge.IsGrouped = true;
}
```